# How to add integers in a string, using only TWO while loops, with one nested in the other

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, nested-loops

here's the question
"Standard input consists of a single addition involving exactly five integer terms.
"271+9730+30+813+5" for example.

I need to add all that while using only max two while loops with one in another.

Im only allowed to use functions such as
if/else
while

can't use lists for this

I've tried saving the first number as "x" and then the second number as "y" and add that and then at the end restart the loop with the string being cut to exclude the first two numbers

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

s = raw_input()
i = 0
y = 0
while i < len(s) and s[i] != "+":
  i = i + 1
  x = s[:i]
  if i < len(s):
    j = i + 1
    while j < len(s) and s[j] != "+":
      j += 1
      y = s[i + i:j]
      s = s[j:]
      i = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think in terms of magnitude. Each time you move one place without hitting a '+' you increase the value of the first digit 10-fold.

```
result=0
s="271+9730+30+813+5"
spot=0
dec=0
i=0
while spot < 4 and i < len(s):
    if s[0] == '+':
      spot+=1;
      s=s[1:];
    if s[i] == '+':
        result = (result) + (int(s[0])*(10**(dec-1)));
        s=s[1:];
        i=0;
        dec=0;
        print s
        print result
    else:
        dec+=1;
        i+=1;
result = result + int(s)
print result
```

EDIT: Alternately, a much more computationally efficient solution using int() and exactly 2 while loops:

```
result=0
s="271+9730+30+813+5"
spot=0
i=0
while spot < 4:
    while s[i] != '+':
       i+= 1;

    result += int(s[0:i]);
    s=s[i+1:];
    i=0;
    print "remaining string: " + s
    print "current result: " + str(result)
    spot+=1;
result += int(s)
print "final result: " + str(result)
```

Comment: That works, but it says I need to use two while loops, so I need to slot another while loop somewhere in there

Comment: original post said max 2 while loops, if 2 are required, then you can split the first one into 2 by separating the 'and'.  Also, I'm not sure the legality of using the `int` function here.  If `int` is legal I believe there is much more efficient function that doesn't loop through the same integer n! times!

Comment: yeah sorry, I thought it was max two loops because I did it with 5, but when I put it in , it said exactly two loops, yeah I think int() should be fine for it

Comment: sorry I'm confused on how to split it into 2, I either get infinite loops or an empty output

Comment: Thanks man appreciate it, this was so annoying, hate these questions were I'm not allowed to do certain stuff, I doubt my employer will put me in handicapped situations like that

Comment: Believe me, any large employer will give you much larger bureaucratic handicaps to overcome!